# Vim create a blank buffer instead of exiting

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

I want to start using Vim as my main editor, as I heard it is really awesome and productive. So I installed a bunch of plugins using Pathogen, and created a nice, long `.vimrc` file.
One of the plugins I use (and really like) is `NERDTree`, so I copied the following lines into my `.vimrc` file from the NERDTree git repository:

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in = 1
autocmd VimEnter *
      \ NERDTree |
      \ wincmd p
autocmd VimEnter *
      \ if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") |
      \ NERDTree |
      \ wincmd p |
      \ endif
autocmd VimEnter *
      \ if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") |
      \ exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] |
      \ wincmd p |
      \ ene |
      \ endif
autocmd BufEnter *
      \ if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) |
      \ q |
      \ endif
```

Now to my question: I want to make it so no matter what, vim won't quit unless I *explicitly* tell it to (using a special command like `:Quit` or using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> on MacVim). So basically, if I only have, say, a buffer containing a file open along with a NERDTree buffer (or even if I just have a single buffer open, no NERDTree), when I `:q` or `:close` that buffer, I want it to present me with a blank buffer, like when you just open vim. But I am not sure how to script that, so I would love some help on what to add to my `.vimrc`

TL;DR: How do you make Vim only exit using an explicit command, and not when you quit the last buffer?

**(EDIT: Read the comments to @romainl's answer for more clarification about what exactly I'm looking for.**

P.S. Here's my full `.vimrc` file, just in case:

```
" => Pathogen and FTPlugins Setup
execute  pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin indent on

let mapleader = "\ "

" => Color Theme Options
colorscheme monokai

" => Custom Commands
""""command W  w
""""command Q  q
""""command Wq wq
""""command WQ wq
""""command B  b
command Tabs   set listchars=tab:\|\ ,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
command NoTabs set listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
" =*=> Plugin-Related
" =*=> Theme-Related
command Light
      \ set background=light |
      \ colorscheme solarized
command Dark
      \ set background=dark |
      \ colorscheme solarized

" => Custom Mappings
" =*=> Basic Editor Commands
nnoremap '                  :%s/
                                                        " Find and replace
nnoremap !                  :!
                                                        " Run shell command
nnoremap <C-o>    :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-p>    :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <leader> <C-w>
" =*=> Workdir Manipulation
" nnoremap <C-j>    :lcd %:p:h<CR>
" =*=> Plugin-Related
" =*=*=> NERDTree
noremap  <C-f>    :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
noremap  <C-d>    :NERDTreeFind<CR>
" =*=*=> BufExplorer
nnoremap <Tab>    :BufExplorerHorizontalSplit<CR>

" => Settings
syntax on                                               " Enable syntax highlighting
set number                                              " Show line numbers
set ruler                                               " Show row & column number
set splitright                                          " Vertically split to the right by default
set splitbelow                                          " Horizontally split below by default
set ignorecase                                          " Case-insesitive tab completion
set hidden                                              " Allow buffer switching with unwritten changes
set laststatus=2                                        " Always show status bar (even when there's only one window)
set wildchar=<Tab> wildmenu wildmode=full               " Enhanced tab-completion
set listchars=tab:\|\ ,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<     " Set symbols for hidden characters
set list                                                " Show hidden characters
set autochdir                                           " When opening a file, automatically set workingdir (of the current buffer) to the directory containing that file
set nowrap                                              " Disable line wrapping
" =*=> Tab Settings (commonly overwritten in ftplugins)
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround
set autoindent
set smartindent
set expandtab                                           " Output spaces when pressing <Tab>, not actual tab characters ('\t')
" =*=> Split vertically by default

" =*=> GVim Settings
set guioptions-=r                                       " Remove right-hand scroll bar
set guioptions-=L                                       " Remove left-hand scroll bar
" =*=> Plugin-Related
" =*=*=> NERDTree
let NERDTreeShowHidden = 1                              " Always show hidden files
let NERDTreeShowBookmarks = 1
" =*=*=> NERDCommenter
let g:NERDSpaceDelims = 1                               " Add spaces after comment delimiters by default
let g:NERDCommentEmptyLines = 1                         " Allow commenting and inverting empty lines (useful when commenting a region)
let g:NERDTrimTrailingWhitespace = 1                    " Enable trimming of trailing whitespace when uncommenting

" => AutoCommands
autocmd BufEnter * lcd %:p:h                   " When opening a file, automatically set workingdir (of the current buffer) to the directory containing that file
" =*=>Plugin-Related
" =*=*=> NERDTree
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in = 1
autocmd VimEnter *
      \ NERDTree |
      \ wincmd p
autocmd VimEnter *
      \ if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") |
      \ NERDTree |
      \ wincmd p |
      \ endif
autocmd VimEnter *
      \ if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") |
      \ exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] |
      \ wincmd p |
      \ ene |
      \ endif
autocmd BufEnter *
      \ if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) |
      \ q |
      \ endif
                " Up to here, copied from repository's README.md

" => Miscellanea
highlight NonText    guifg=DimGray ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
highlight SpecialKey guifg=DimGray ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE " Set Hidden Characters Color
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of this? If you want a blank buffer just do `:enew`.

Comment: I know, but my problem is that anytime I want to close a file (because I finished editing it), I `:q` or `:close` it. But most of the time, it completely quite Vim. I want a behavior similar to most editors, where it will just open a blank file

Comment: `:q` is for windows, not buffers.

Comment: Okay... so: A. Is there a way I can make it so when I `:close` the buffer in the last window present it won't quit it, and B. If I have a split and I want to close it, will `:close` work too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete all buffers and leave you in a blank one.

```
:%bd
```

Or as a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :%bd<CR>
```

This will also close all windows and tabs coincidentally because those close automatically if all the buffers are closed. It won't work if you have any unsaved buffers, which is probably what you want. Add a `!` if you're sure you want to close without saving.

I usually want to close just the current buffer, but still have the rest open. So I use this. This won't close anything if there is only one buffer left.

```
:bp|bd#
```

Or as a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :bp\|bd#<CR>
```

**EDIT:**
In response to comment about using `enew` when there is only one buffer left:

```
function! BufferDelete()
    if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')) > 1
        execute "bp|bd#"
    else
        execute "enew|bd#"
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <key> :call BufferDelete()<CR>
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to make it so if there is no buffer left, it will do `:enew|bd#`, *otherwise* it will do `:bp|bd#`, both in the same mapping?

Answer (score 2):

Both `:quit` and `:close` are for windows.

If you *really* want to get rid of a buffer, use `:bdelete` or `:bunload`.

This command replaces the current buffer with a new empty buffer (`:enew`)  and deletes the previous buffer (`:bdelete#`):

```
:enew|bd#
```

You can map it if you want:

```
nnoremap <key> :enew\|bdelete#<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is just what I was looking for. But is there a way ti make it so if there id another buffer open, it will switch to it, or else it will create a new one?

Comment: Also, I should note, in addition to what I said above, when I run the command, if it's not the only *window* open, it will close the window? So:
If there is only one window and one buffer, create a blank one.
If there is only one window and more than one buffer, switch to the next buffer.
If there is more than one window, close the window.

Comment: Also, I should note, `:bdelete` works perfect. The problem is, that sometimes when I use it it gives me the error:
`Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "*":`
`E37: No write since last change`
and exists NERDTree

Comment: Ans sometimes it just completely quits. Can't seem to find the pattern :/